# Call Hung up listener for asterisk

Tags: php, asterisk, voip, agi

I'm developing a web application for call operators to enter the customer information and their call information into database.
The important point is that call system is served by asterisk and has no communication with my web app. operators enter call information manually by listening to the call.

I don't whether it is possible or not, But I want to set a listener for call hang up event generated by asterisk so that it asterisk make a request containing call summary to my php code.

Is it possible? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is posible by listen via AMI manager interface and waiting for Hangup

You can use for example perl Asterisk::AMI class for that(example have on cpan for that class)